# Denying access to non operating drive on dual boot

Tags: hard-drive, multi-boot, windows-11

I have a PC with 2 drives with Windows 11 Home on each drive on dual boot.

I would like to deny access to the non operating drive which ever drive I boot on.

Effectively, when Drive 1 is the active operating drive, it will not be able to access Drive 2 and vice versa.

Any ideas on how to do it ?

Thanks :)

Comment: It would help if you added why you want this to know if it is possible. Because yes, one can simply configure it to not be there, but given that this is not too hard to do, I assume you would not be asking the question here if that were the case.

Comment: ...but given that this is not too hard to do, I assume.. -->Nope, I am not tech savy. What you are proposing seems to be what I want but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click the startbutton, disk management and from there, find the disk you want to hide.

On the left side, right-click the disk and choose Offline. This will essentially turn the disk off in this Windows installation. The content is safe though.

Reboot to the other windows installation and take the other disk offline there to get the same.

Alternatively, you can select the driveletter, rightclick it and select Change Drive letter and Paths... then click the drive letter, and press remove. This only removes the letter, not any content. The disk will vanish from Windows Explorer.

That being said, it just as easy to reverse this change as to make this change, so it is not a very secure way to do this. It would definitely beneft talking about the problem and persisting that they don't change the content. You can hide the drive still to prevent any accidental changes such as a virus going wild that will only affect their drive, and not yours.

Comment: Feel free to press the checkbox on the answer that helped you most to let others know you no longer need help.

Comment: It seems to me that your solution suffers from the same criticism that you applied to mine.

Comment: @harrymc Yes and no. I added that it can be undone easily, so you need to explicitly tell the children that they cannot have access. But the biggest difference is that your answer does not actually add how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple : In each Windows instance, do not assign a drive-letter to the
disk of the other one.

No drive-letter means no access.

Comment: And what exactly would anyone stop from assigning it again? Not sure this is what OP is after.

Comment: @LPChip: If the hacker has Administrator permissions - nothing will stop him, except (1) Encrypting the disks, (2) Physically taking the disk out.

Comment: I'm not talking about hackers though. I'm talking about that this could be a measure to separate operating systems between parents and  childrens.

Comment: @LPChip: Same argument if he gave Administrator permissions to his children, or if he gave away the password to the other Windows instance.

Comment: And that is exactly my point. Its not entirely clear what OP's intentions are, but if this is done for security reasons, then the answer is going to be: not possible, rather than: just hide the drive letter.

Comment: @LPChip: You're building on a supposition, rather than just asking the poster.

Comment: I did ask the poster, see my comment below the question.

Comment: Wow, such activity, thanks everybody :) My intend is to not have my teenager messes up my drive as we share the same computer ;)